# Need RobotFramework Appium standalone jar with all dependencies

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, robotframework

I am integrating RobotFramework with Appium using jython.

I have installed Appium using command

```
jython -m pip install robotframework-appiumLibrary
```

This works fine, but i am looking for standalone jar which contains robotFramework integrated with  Appium with all dependencies

**Note : I am Using RobotFramework 3.0 with Java**

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, no such thing exist.

Not that it is exactly what you are looking for but: there is docker container easy to use:

[Docker Hub Link for robotframework-appiumlibrary](https://hub.docker.com/r/qualifylabs/robotframework-appium-docker)